# input range and calculation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, calculation

I have a problem that I have input range so I used for discount to my total price, and when I change the input range, I also want to change the total calculation because the input range is the percentage of the initial total. So on change the input range most the discount most change too and the price also change.

**My html:**

```
<div class="slider2">
    <div class="range2">
        <input type="range" name="date3" id="date3" min="0" max="100" step="1" ng-model="ctrl2.inputAge2" value="Please enter the year of build" required>
        <P class="setyear2">15000 </P>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <p>INITIAL TOTAL</p>
    <P>{{totalPrice | number}} $</P>
</div>
<div>
    <p>discount</p>
    <P>{{ ctrl2.inputAge2 }} %</P>
</div>
<div>
    <p>TOTAL price</p>
    <P>{{getTotal1()  | number}} $</P>
</div>
```

**and javascript:**

```
$scope.totalPrice = 170 ; 
var ctrl2 = this;
    ctrl2.inputAge2 = 10;

    $.fn.WBslider3 = function () {
      return this.each(function () {
        var $_this = $(this),
          $_date3 = $('input', $_this),
          $_title3 = $('.setyear3', $_this),
          thumbwidth = 50, // set this to the pixel width of the thumb
          yrnow3 = 100;

        // set range max to current year
        $_date3.attr('max', yrnow3);
        $('.endyear3', $_this).text(yrnow3);
        $_date3.val(yrnow3 - 10); // -10 years, just because...

        $_date3.on('input change keyup', function () {
          var $_this = $(this),
            val = parseInt($_date3.val(), 10);




          $_title3.text(val);

          var pos = (val - $_date3.attr('min')) / ($_date3.attr('max') - $_date3.attr('min'));

          // position the title with the thumb
          var thumbCorrect = thumbwidth * (pos - 0.5) * -1,
            titlepos = Math.round((pos * $_date3.width()) - thumbwidth / 4 + thumbCorrect);

          $_title3.css({
            'left': titlepos
          });

          // show "progress" on the track
          pos = Math.round(pos * 99); // to hide stuff behide the thumb
          var grad = 'linear-gradient(90deg, #A7A7A7 ' + pos + '%,#FFE014 ' + (pos + 1) + '%)';
          $_date3.css({
            'background': grad
          });

        }).on('focus', function () {
          if (isNaN($(this).val())) {
            $(this).val(0);
          }
        }).trigger('change');

        $(window).on('resize', function () {
          $_date3.trigger('change');
        });
      });
    };

    $(function () {

      $('.slider3').WBslider3();

    });



    $scope.getTotal1 = function () {
      var total1 = 0;
      total1 = ($scope.totalPrice + ctrl2.inputAge2);
      return total1;
    }
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate it in html mostly, also use the toFixed method of Number.:

```
<div class="slider2">
      <div class="range2">
          <input type="range" name="date3" id="date3" min="0" max="100" step="1" ng-model="discount"
              value="Please enter the year of build" required>
          <P class="setyear2">15000 </P>
      </div>
  </div>

<div>
 <b >INITIAL TOTAL</b>
  <P>{{totalPrice }} $</P>
</div>
<div>
    <b>discount</b>
  <P>{{ discount }} %</P>
</div>
<div>
 <b>TOTAL price</b>
  <P>{{(totalPrice - (totalPrice*discount)/100).toFixed(2)}} $</P>
</div>
```

Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/E3uHDQpdE8e9HoDbiivs?p=preview